# Angular and mat-tab-nav-bar: How to Maintain Horizontal Scroll using router.Navigate

Tags: css, button, angular-material

I am using Angular and mat-tab-nav-bar, and I have a reactive site.  I am trying to keep the selected menu item in view no matter the page size.

(using a router to navigate onclick, so the page reloads)

I can kind of achieve it by grabbing the translateX location and reapplying it (which brings the correct menu item into view) but then the buttons don't react correctly. (the first button is still disabled and clicking the forward button brings us back to the second position as if it wasn't clicked before).

I don't have a stackblitz or anything, I am just wondering if anybody has dealt with this and if I can ultimately access those buttons created by mat-tab-nav-bar to set them as disabled/enabled and modify their inner magic.   Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.